# How to define a start index in my c program?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on a program but currently it asks for let you enter the values.

```
ex.

    How many number you want to enter?
    5

    Type in the numbers.
    1 2 3 4 5
```

But I want to pre-define the numbers like;

> **int i[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}**

How to do that?

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main ()
{
 int number[30];
 int i,n,a,j;

 printf ("Enter the value of n\n");
 scanf ("%d",&n);

 printf ("Enter the numbers\n");
 for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
  scanf ("%d", &number[i]);

 printf ("Enter the position of the element to split the array \n");
 scanf ("%d",&a);

 for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
 {
  number[n] = number[0];

  for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
  {
   number[j] = number[j+1];
  }
 }

 printf("The resultant array is\n");
 for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
 {
  printf ("%d\n",number[i]);
 }
 getch();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want to hard-code (*predefine*) it, what's stopping you?

Comment: @KenWhite whenever I try to make it into the form i[5] = {1,2,3,4,5} I get error c2040 differs in levels of indirection from... etc.

Comment: It should be `int numbers[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`.

Comment: That information should be in your question, so it's clear what problem you're asking for help solving. You should [edit] to include it there instead of posting it in a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{

  int number[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int i,n=5,a,j;
  printf ("Enter the position of the element to split the array \n");
  scanf ("%d",&a);

  for (i=0; i<a; ++i)
  {
    number[n] = number[0];

    for (j=0; j<n; ++j)
    {
      number[j] = number[j+1];
    }
  }

  printf("The resultant array is\n");
  for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {
    printf ("%d\n",number[i]);
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here. You should include some text how your code provides a solution and why, so that it teaches rather than provides a copy/paste answer.

Comment: Edit: When I debug and quit it gives an error "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'number' was corrupted."

Comment: You don't need to specify the array.  if you write `int number[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` the compiler will figure out the size for you

Comment: [Click here to see my screen](http://i.imgur.com/a1nHc6H.jpg) I've tried it but program still gives an error while quitting. This time I really have no idea.

Comment: @cprogramdatabase:  You have `n` items in your array.  The last index is `n-1` because arrays start at index 0.  Therefore, `number[n] = number[0];` is assigning to an index that is outside of your array.  But please, don't keep piling on more and more questions to this one every time you encounter a new bug in your program.  Either ask a new question or better yet, use your debugger and single step through your program.

Comment: This code is not mine .i only edited few lines and posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a maximum limit of the numbers to insert?
If yes, you can initialize your using array with predefined numbers, let's say:

```
int predefined[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

and replace values when needed.

Comment: I have exact amnount of numbers to insert they're 5.
I tried run the code above provided by @AnuragGoel it works but gives an error after debug.

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'number' was corrupted."

Comment: Try what suggested here, and tell us the result. What does it stop you from initializing your array, as far as you know and have statically set its size?

Comment: [Click here to see my screen](http://i.imgur.com/a1nHc6H.jpg) I've also tried this solution too but the program still gives an error while quitting. This time I really have no idea. @NickL (In the image there is no 5 but it doesn't matter if put or not quit gives an error.

EDIT: Nevermind, fixed it. Works awesome thank you!